# Unable to locate ADB, but adb.exe is still exist on Sdk Platforms-tool folder

Tags: android, sdk, adb, emulation, android-virtual-device

When I run AVD, it shows dialog

> Unable to locate ADB

I've tried many solution and I found that my adb.exe exist on Sdk Platforms-tool folder but the dialog still shows up

I've make that Sdk Platforms-tool folder in exception Avast folder and also restarted my windows

Comment: Have you added your SDK directory and path to the platform-tools to the environment variables?

Comment: @nithinpp yes i have done that before

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the tool is corrupted, so I suggest you down it via [official links](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.)

After downloading, open the terminal and run below commands

```
// change to the install location
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\
adb kill-server
```